# Noaudit all on schema.table-name not working

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, database-administration, auditing

We have one system status table A in DB and Application process select and update on that table for 4 times in one seconds so huge audit logs are generating.

So I have tried

```
NOAUDIT ALL on schema.A;
```

- but still audit logs are generated why?
- and how do I find out previously fired Audit statement?

Comment: using 12c and audit trail is set to OS level.

Answer (score 0):

- You must restart the sessions for them to stop logging in the trail.
- Check that you have no trigger on that table  who would do the auditing above Oracle's mechanism